# C#: Tests.* namespace hides another namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have 2 namespaces:
Project.Core;
Tests.Project.Core;

In **Project.Core** there is a Class named "**Text**". In **Tests.Project.Core.TextTests** (where I place tests for Text) I also use **NUnit** which **also has a class Text**.
I thought: "OK, make it fully qualified." and wrote Project.Core.Text.

Now the compiler complains that it can't find Project.Core.Text. This is because the **namespace-part** "Project.Core" is also found in "**Tests.** Project.Core" (!) and it doesn't realise that it's a fully qualified name already...

What can I do to make the compiler select the right class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [global](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28VS.80%29.aspx) keyword:

```
var text = new global::Project.Core.Text()
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found another way (namespace alias): using ProjectCore = Project.Core; but your solution is also working - accepted!